# Finding a maximum subarray in worst-case linear time

Tags: maximum-subarray

Here's a problem of CLRS:

Use the following ideas to develop a nonrecursive, linear-time algorithm for the maximum-subarray problem. Start at the left end of the array, and progress toward the right, keeping track of the maximum subarray seen so far. Knowing a maximum subarray of $A[1..j]$, extend the answer to find a maximum subarray ending at index $j + 1$ by using the following observation: a maximum subarray of $A[1..j + 1]$ is either a maximum subarray of $A[1..j]$ or a subarray $A[i..j + 1]$, for some
$1 \leq i \leq j + 1$. Determine a maximum subarray of the form $A[i..j + 1]$ in constant time based on knowing a maximum subarray ending at index $j$.

Now this is a solution to it:

```
ITERATIVE-FIND-MAXIMUM-SUBARRAY(A)
 n = A.length
 max-sum = -∞
 sum = -∞
 for j = 1 to n:
     currentHigh = j
     if sum > 0:
         sum = sum + A[j]
     else
         currentLow = j
         sum = A[j]
     if sum > max-sum:
         max-sum = sum
         low = currentLow
         high = currentHigh
 return (low, high, max-sum)
```

I understand how `max-sum` is indeed the sum of a maximum subarray but I can't figure out how `low` and `high` are the indices of such a subarray. I don't know what the procedure is and how it updates these variables in each iteration. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sum` computes the value of maximum subarray of the form $A[i..j+1]$. And, `currentlow`  is $i$ and `currenthigh` is $j+1$. Note that `currenthigh` is incrementing in every iteration by $1$ that means it is pointing to current $j$ always.

If `sum>0` (value of maximum subarray of the form $A[i..j]$), then it is always better to make `new-sum = sum + A[j+1]` because then `sum + A[j+1] > A[j+1,j+1]` irrespective of whether $A[j+1]$ is negative or positive. Here, `new-sum`: value of maximum subarray of the form $A[i..j+1]$.

Similarly, if `sum<0`, then it is always better to make the `new-sum = A[j+1,j+1]` because `sum + A[j+1] < A[j+1][j+1]` irrespective of whether $A[j+1]$ is negative or positive.

Therefore, the correct `sum` is computed in the first `if else` statement.

After that, you are right that `max-sum` is the value of maximum subarray of $A[1,j+1]$. And, `low` and `high` are its indices. Note that they do not change unless `sum` > `max-sum` that should be the case as per the DP method.